# Filter int, float in list, Python

Tags: python

I have:

```
list = [1, 2, 'A', True, -1, -2.5, 7, [1, 2], False]
```

I want to have `filter_list(int,float)`

Expected: `[1, 2, -1, -2.5, 7]`

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Side-note: Do you want to allow subclasses of the types? Because `bool` *is* a subclass of `int`, which will mean `True` and `False` aren't removed.

Comment: I did try isdigit() or """for x in list: try: yield float(x) except ValueError: pass """ but not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can filter it:

```
n = [i for i in list if (type(i) is float or type(i) is int)]
```

we only take the values that are either float or int.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did try isdigit()  or """for x in list:
        try:
            yield float(x)
        except ValueError:    
            pass  """                     but not work